# Python prints URL from img + going to new page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to enter the next page link in a variable at the end of the link.

I'm new in Python :(

Here is my script:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen('https://test.com/index/index/2')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
for image in images: 
    print(image['src']+'\n')
```

The script output can be found at:
https://1.amazonaws.com/awer/adc/45521192_15642345066.jpg

Can I make it print only 45521192 
so the output will be like this:

```
45521192
45521193
45521194
45521195
```

Comment: The URL to the image seems to be wrong. I can' see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, just change `print(image['src']+'\n')` to:

```
print(image['src'].split('/')[-1].split('_')[0])
```

Comment: thx a lot <<<<<
now how can i make it goin to the new page in this url like this 
https://test.com/index/index/1

i want number from 1 until 5 or until the page in html elemnt empty 
i did search but it work in selenuim :(